# Cutting lines and text evenly on puzzles (Illustrator)

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Trying to cut lines and text so when two puzzles are separated these lines and text are cut in a correct way. How to do it the shortest way?

[image]

Upadating post:

I followed your advice but when I try to separate this picture and have this square on top selected I get this message:
"The filter can't make this operation because more than one object is selected"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: End]

Before doing it, there are some things to consider:

- The text must be outlined, with the text selected <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> Win
- The big circle must have the stroke aligned outside

[image: stroke]

- The circle must be expanded: **Menu Object** > **Expand Appearance**

[image: Expand Appearance]

- It's necessary to add the inner circle as a separate shape

Once these steps are completed, select only the path that will make the cut and go to menu **Object** > **Path** > **Divide Objects Below**, ungroup the text, select the elements of each part and separate them.

[image: End]

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. Just one more thing - how to bring back this puzzle piece afterwards? Eventually I need to have these objects divided + this puzzle shape must stay, too.

Comment: Copy/Paste, duplicate it or keep it in a symbol library

Comment: Ok, but when I paste it back it doesn't go to the same place as before. Therefore it's hard to place it exactly in the same spot.

Comment: Instead of paste, use Past in front: Cmd + F mac or Ctrl + F win

Comment: Wow, this is magic :) Many thanks. You must be a great company to work with!

Comment: Please have a look at my updated post. Thank you in advance.